# TeX Live 2018: unicode-math does not allow using \mathcal or \mathbf as subscript or superscript without brackets

Tags: fonts, texlive, unicode-math

I have upgraded my TeX Live system to the 2018 version and realized a strange behavior: One can no longer use `\mathcal` as a subscript or a superscript without brackets. Example:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$a_\mathcal{S}$ % not working

$a^\mathcal{S}$ % not working

$a_{\mathcal{S}}$ % with brackets, working

$a_\mathbf{S}$ % boldface is working
\end{document}
```

My questions are: Is this a bug or a feature? If it's a bug, then how to fix it? If it's a feature, then why?

Thank you very much in advance!

**Update:** After posting the question I realized that `\mathbf` without brackets is also not allowed, if it is followed by something else. For example:

```
$a^\mathbf{s}(x)$ % not working

$a_\mathbf{s}^x$ % not working

$a^{\mathbf{s}}(x)$ % working

$a_{\mathbf{s}}^x$ % working
```

Comment: Can this posting be closed as "has already been solved"?

Comment: @Mico No my questions are still not answered ;)

Comment: Because the argument to `_` is not a single token but `\mathbf{x}`. This is only consistent with other argument parsing. If the argument is more than a single token, you have to enclose it in braces.

Comment: @Mico I see your point. Maybe I was not clear enough in my question: all of the expression tagged by "not working" above, they are all working in TeX Live 2015. The problem occurred to me only after the upgrade to the 2018 version. In addition, **if the unicode-math package is removed, then they are also all working**, without any warning. That means the TeX syntax is correct (which of course contradicts your above argument). In conclusion, this issue is specific to unicode-math only, and not to TeX in general.

Comment: The syntax without braces is *wrong*. You only were lucky until now that due to some implementation details it didn't lead to errors.  This can happen. Not every input error is punished.

Comment: Mhhh, I'd argue that the TeX syntax without braces is actually incorrect and some things work by accident even though they should not (or at least: need not). Try `$a_\sqrt{n}$` or `a_\foo{n}` where `\foo` is `\newcommand*{\foo}[#1]{X#1Y}`. They are syntactically similar to your constructions, yet cause errors or do not give the expected output.

Comment: @Mico the unbraced syntax is wrong because documented latex syntax for subscripts is specified as using braces, not by reference to tex primitive behaviour. `a_\mathcal{S}` works in classic latex and worked in unicode-math until last year https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/448

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks for this. I've deleted my earlier comment. I think you should write up your comment as a stand-alone answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- that statement, especially the last sentence, is worthy of working in embroidery and framing.